# WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I downloaded binary version for WSO2 ESB 4.0.3
Now when i run wso2server.bat , it simply executes for 2-3 seconds and quits with followin output:

```
>wso2server.bat
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_24
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to D:\iprint\WSO2ES~1.3\bin\..
[2012-11-08 10:02:12,250]  INFO - Main Initializing system...
[2012-11-08 10:02:12,375]  INFO - HttpTransport Created Connector [HTTP_11_NIO:/
/*:9763]
[2012-11-08 10:02:12,390]  INFO - HttpTransport Created Connector [HTTPS_11_NIO:
//*:9443]
[2012-11-08 10:02:12,453]  INFO - TomcatCarbonWebappDeployer Deployed Carbon web
app: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[defaulthost].StandardContext[/]
[2012-11-08 10:02:12,593]  INFO - TransactionFactory Starting Atomikos Transacti
on Manager 3.7.0
>
```

I can not find anything in the logs as well.
The documentation also seems to be poor for 4.0.3 on wso2.org site as there is no step on how to configure DB for the ESB.

Thanks
deepak

Answer (score -1):

WSO2 ESB documentation clearly specifies these information. As you are working with 4.0.3 version, this is the doc location. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403

And please follow up; http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/Installing+ESB+on+Windows+from+Binary+Distribution to run the ESB on windows.

Adding a db: 
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/Adding+a+Database

**FYI**: Latest WSO2 ESB can be downloaded from http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/

ESB 4.5.1 doc: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Enterprise+Service+Bus+Documentation

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: I tried 4.5.1 before going to 4.0.3.But with 4.5.1 even , i faced the same issue.ESB server was not getting started and the following error was displayed:2012-11-06 22:00:46,078 [-] [Start Level Event Dispatcher]  WARN ValidationResultPrinter RAM size (MB): 2047 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048..so i thought of moving to older and stable release , but to no aail.Even the forums do not have enough information on these errors.

Comment: I tried the same steps as in the links that you shared.But the esb is not coming up and there is nothing in the logs as well.The ouput as pasted above is there in the command window.

Comment: Check whether your CARBON_HOME environment variable is pointing to ESB 4.0.3 properly. I see the following line in your log "CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to D:\iprint\WSO2ES~1.3\bin\.." which is somewhat suspicious. Note the WSO2ES~1.3 part. I have started WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 in windows with zero effort. Just unzip and run the wso2server.bat file.